# 2 round tickets plus 1 back ticket to Thailand

Tags: thailand, return-tickets

I would buy tickets from Denmark to Thailand and back.
Travel from 17th september and back home 5th october cost me about 40,000 thb.

Travel from 17th september and back home 5th december cost me only 10,000 thb.
One way ticket from Thailand to Denmark for 5th october cost only 16,000 thb.
So together for 3 tickets i could pay only 26,000 thb instead 40,000 thb.

It is possible and legal make like this?
Could i have problems with airlines or immigration in Thailand?
I have 30 days tourist visa in Thailand after landing in Thailand.

Thank you

Comment: Just remember to bring *both* itineraries with you to check-in and immigration because occasionally they ask to see your return ticket.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes**, that's totally fine.  The practice is known as "nested ticketing" and is quite common.

Usually when using nested tickets you start with a one-way and add in return flights, but you're doing it the other way around, which is also fine.

The one part airlines don't like is throwing away your return ticket, but for a one-off, that's not going to be an issue either.  You might even want to double down: find a cheap return fare *from* Thailand and throw away the return leg -- or use it come back to Thailand for another visit!

Comment: Agree. Just as a side note, what is not allowed (you'll be refused by most airlines) is to discard one leg and try to flight in the next. Normally airlines assume that if you have not imbarked in a previous flight, you have discarded your complete trip.

Comment: Make sure you can convince the airline to check you in with 30 days visa and almost 3 months ticket.

Comment: @vasin1987 This shouldn't be an issue, they can just show the other ticket if needed.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most common patterns is crossed bookings:

- Your original plan is to go from date A to date B
- But having another trip from date C to date D would be great as well
- Instead of booking tickets for dates A/B and C/D, you book A/D and (the other way around) B/C.

Depending on the fare rules this can often be a lot cheaper, because cheaper fares often have minimum stay requirements.

Answer (score 2):

> Could I have problems with airlines?

Some airlines have policies against it, e.g. [Delta](https://www.delta.com/us/en/booking-information/fare-classes-and-tickets/ticket-rules-restrictions)

> While not an exclusive list, the following ticketing practices are prohibited: [...] **Throw-away ticketing**: use of discounted round-trip excursion fares for one-way travel.

But it is [very unlikely](https://www.insider.com/how-to-save-money-on-flights-nested-ticketing) to be enforced, unless perhaps if one does it very frequently.

FYI: [Which flight search engines show cheapest flight options including throw-away ticketing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/176235/1810)

Answer (score 2):

With immigration, probably not since you can show them the return ticket within visa validity.

With airline, however, they will check if you have a valid visa for the period of your ticket. Since your visa is only 30 days they may not accept you for the flight. If you show them another one-way ticket, that shows your intention to throw away part of the ticket. Whether that is allowed or not depends on the airline.