# Which flight search engines show the flight options sorted by price and including throw-away ticketing?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, flight-search-engines

Throw-away ticketing [sometimes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/176215/1810) yields the cheapest flight option. Which flight search engines show the flight options sorted by price and including throw-away ticketing?